# Remove owl carousel item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I know that there are some associated questions about it, I tried all solutions and read all documentation, but w/o result.

I am initializing a Owl carousel :

> HTML

In HTML, I have 2 items :

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme all_diplomas">
    <div class="item diploma-0">
        <div class="content_diplomas">
            <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/6.jpg"><i
                    class="material-icons">search</i></a>
            <figure><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""></figure>
        </div>
    <button class="waves-effect delete-diploma waves-blue diploma-0" type="button"><span>x</span> </button>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="add_diplomas">
            <div class="item_add_diplomas">
                <span class="plus_add">+</span>
                <span class="txt_btn">Add diploma<br></span>
                <input id="generateInputsForDiplomas">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JS :

```
  $(".all_diplomas").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 15,
        responsive: {
            1000: {
                items: 4
            },
            1200: {
                items: 2
            }
        },

    });
```

Next, after my script initialization :

```
$('input#generateInputsForDiplomas').on('click',function() {
   var template = '<div class="item diploma-' + index + '"> <div class="content_diplomas"> <a class="diploma-' + index + '" data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/3.jpg"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>' +
                       '<figure><img src="images/3.jpg" class="addedDiplomaInput diploma-' + index +  '"alt=""></figure> </div> </div>'
                       + '<button class="waves-effect delete-diploma waves-blue ' + classes + '" type="button"><span>x</span> </button>';

        var newEl= $('.all_diplomas').trigger('add.owl.carousel', [template, 33]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

> Code above just adds a block of owl-item with one image and some id-s
>   and classes.
>
> Then, it appends this template to position 33 and refreshes the
>   carousel

Them, each element has a delete button associated to `owl-item class`

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.delete-diploma',function() {
 $(".all_diplomas").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', 33).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

That's the thing. When adding an element, from documentation, I am setting the position for this element explicitly - like 33. But when I am calling the button that is responsable to remove item with position 33, it deletes entire slider, or sometimes unexpected behavior.

The reason why I'm calling position explicitly, because I need to know each item's index, because when calling delete button, to know item with which position to delete.  Documentation offers callbacks that has this information, but not for "add" event.

How can I lifehack that problem? I want to add n-items to carousel, and each this block with image to has it's own delete button. So, when calling this button, it will delete that element and refresh the Owl. I tried with pure jQuery to delete parents and so on... but Owl generates some other classes, and because of it, item is deleted, but empty spaces in slider remains.